Looking for a movie about a teen being guided by his late brother
This movie came out in the 80s. This kid's dead brother comes back to help him cope with life as a teenager (dating, fending off bullies). Thing is, his brother comes in the form of a stranger, and not his brother's likeness. All I remember is at the end of the movie, the brother, after completing his task, says goodbye. As he takes off in his hot rod, the younger brother realizes it's his brother and yells out his name.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a question title that describes the movie you're looking for a bit more. It's clear you're looking for a movie, neither are you the first one to do so.

That was all I could remember. I don't even know who starred in the film. It was a "coming of age" film of the 80s. The car was a black muscle car.

The Wraith (1986)

The Wraith tells the story of a murdered Arizona teen who
  mysteriously returns from the dead as an all-powerful drag racing
  wraith intent on taking revenge on a gang of car thieves and their
  psychotic leader, who murdered the teen so the leader could then exert
  emotional control over the dead teen's girlfriend using
  intimidation......
... Jake drives the Turbo Interceptor to Big Kay's, startling his
  brother Billy. Jake hands over the keys to the supercar, noting '"It's
  the only one in existence; it does very special things". He then tells
  Billy that his work here is finished. Billy asks, "Who are you, bro"?
  To this, Jake wryly replies, "You said it, Billy ... the instructions
  are in the glove compartment". As Jake rides off on his dirt bike,
  Billy comes to the grief-stricken realization that Jake is somehow his
  returned older brother, Jamie.





That sounds like it. Thanks, I'll check it out.
